# Adding Custom Control Dynamically in c# application

Tags: c#, dll

I have created two custom controls. On the basis of features any one of them will be selected and used in C# application. I have loaded the desired control but how i can use there functions e.g There is a public function of my control  LoadXML() . Both controls contain this function.
Only one control will be loaded at one time.

Comment: How do you load them? Do you know where they are loaded? When do you have to call LoadXML()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an instance of your control, then add it to the form, after that you can call its public exposed methods.

```
 TestControl myTestControl = new TestControl();
 this.Controls.Add(myTestControl);
 myTestControl.LoadXML();
```

If you are loading controls through dll, try this to call the method:

```
    // Use the file name to load the assembly into the current
    // application domain.
    Assembly a = Assembly.Load("example");
    // Get the type to use.
    Type myType = a.GetType("Example");
    // Get the method to call.
    MethodInfo myMethod = myType.GetMethod("MethodA");
    // Create an instance.
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
    // Execute the method.
    myMethod.Invoke(obj, null);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39.aspx

Comment: myassembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(Application.StartupPath + "\\PDF" + "\\x86" + "\\PDFView" + ".dll");
            }
        
         
            

            if (myassembly != null)
            {
                Type t = myassembly.GetType("PDFView.PDFViewer");
                cc = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                this.Controls.Add(cc);
                cc.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
                cc.Show();

Comment: i am loading from .dll of both controls. The application will decide on runtime which .dll will be loaded

Comment: cc = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(t); Here cast to your particular control type, instead of Control

Comment: i have casted to other types but still the methods are not accessible in my application. If i call them then there is compile time errors

Comment: Try this:  // Use the file name to load the assembly into the current
        // application domain.
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load("example");
        // Get the type to use.
        Type myType = a.GetType("Example");
        // Get the method to call.
        MethodInfo myMethod = myType.GetMethod("MethodA");
        // Create an instance.
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
        // Execute the method.
        myMethod.Invoke(obj, null); //Check out this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you question properly, you should create an interface and add the function `LoadXML()` to it. Implement the interface on your custom controls. Now you can create the object of the interface and initialize it with your desired control.

```
interface MyInterface
    {
        void LoadXML();
    }
```

In your user control, implement `MyInterface`

```
public class UserControl1 : UserControl, MyInterface
    {
        public void LoadXML()
        {
          ...  //do what you want
        }
    }
```

Same for `UserControl2`
Now load the desired user control in the interface object and call `LoadXML()`,

```
 class Class
    {
        MyInterface control;

        public Class()
        {
            if (condition == true)
                control = new UserControl1();
            else
                control = new UserControl2();

            control.LoadXML();
        }
    }
```

Hopefully it will help.